# Why "image_read_svg" could not work in R?

Tags: r, image-processing

I think I followed correctly from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#converting_formats). But why I got the error?

```
> library(magick)
Warning message:
package ‘magick’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
> tiger <- image_read_svg('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg', width = 400)
Error: could not find function "image_read_svg"
```

---

The version of `magick` is 0.4, how to install a newer version? I tried `install.packages("magick")` but it is still 0.4

```
> packageVersion("magick")
[1] ‘0.4’
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an error with this function in `magick` version 2.2. Not same exact, but related enough that this may be useful:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rsvg’
```

My error is due to R package `rsvg` not being installed automatically during my installation of `magick`. This may be your problem also. Installing it manually made function `magick::image_read_svg` work.

```
install.packages("rsvg")
library(rsvg)
library(magick)
tiger <- image_read_svg('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg', width = 400)
print(tiger)
```

You should see a tiger image.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your version of `magick` does not have that function. We can check using `apicheck` (my own package, available [on github](https://github.com/hughjonesd/apicheck)).

```
library(apicheck)
when_fun_exists("magick::image_read_svg") # this will take some time...
```

But I am showing off. We could also just check the [NEWS file on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/NEWS):

> 1.8
>
> - Export image_read_svg() and image_read_pdf()

Bet your version is before 1.8. You can check using `packageVersion`.

Comment: I could not install 'apicheck'

Comment: It's on github, not cran. You have to use `devtools::install_github`. It's not necessary anyway. Just check your version of `magick`.